# Meteor client can't connect to server

Tags: websocket, meteor, ddp

At least half of the time, when a client loads my [Meteor](http://meteor.com) app, it can't connect to the server.

If I run this in the console:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
  console.log(Meteor.status());
});
```

I can see that the client is connecting, disconnected, reconnecting repeatedly.

[image]

If I open the Network tab in Chrome's dev tools I can see that about every second or two, another WebSocket request is made.

[image]

**What could be causing this?**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try disabling WebSockets? Try running your meteor app with following env variable

```
export DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS=true
```

This suggestion was posted by [Arunoda on CodersClan](http://www.codersclan.net/ticket/96).

Comment: Any idea how to disable websockets on meteor.com hosting?